# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Shows error "System program problem detected", See details

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I've attached some  [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN3XV.jpg) and [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVTi3.jpg) here.

[image]

[image]

It shows the window as soon as I boot up. There also appears a (-) red minus sign which tells me that a problem occured while checking updates, and when I click "Show updates" it tells me that the Software Updater has crashed unexpectedly.

I am unable to update it (I wish to upgrade to 16.04 LTS), nor solve the problem. Any solutions?

Comment: No it is not, I understand that it is a problem notification. Rather, I intend to solve my problem than know what that icon means. Hope you understand.

Comment: Appreciate your intentions but what I am able to see is the similarity in the issue and it's solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Can you open a terminal:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

any errors will show up there, and it tries to give you ideas as to how you might fix them as well.

Chris

Comment: Ok so I tried that, looks like it went all okay, have a look at these shots : [Screenshot 3] [1] and [Screenshot 4] [2]. But it did not download any heavy updates, but only in kBs, and it took only 2 mins. What now?

Comment: Ok so I tried that, looks like it went all okay, have a look at these shots : [http://imgur.com/nm3zxV3 and http://imgur.com/7FHmU8M. But it did not download any heavy updates, but only in kBs, and it took only 2 mins. What now?

Comment: So no errors?

The next command you can try is sudo apt-get upgrade, although the first is all you should really need.  I have seen that same triangle thing and if the updater doesn't clear it, and these two commands don't then I am not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: This worked! It seems. The terminal notified me of around 293MB of updates. I confirmed with a Y, and it is updating now. Also, the GUI of the Software Updater window came up automatically, which was crashing earlier, notifying updates worth 380MB. I am not sure about the difference in MBs, hope everything goes well. Thanks @Christopher Angulo-Bertram :)

Comment: No problem, have a good night and vote me up.  :-)